# Cell with specific values only

Tags: validation, excel, vba

I need a macro to show a msgbox whenever an invalid value is posted. I need that cell to only accept values in this format "LLXXXXXXX" where L is letter and X is number. I'm using Data validation to show an error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Why isn't data validation working?  What's your setup for that? You could edit the Error Alert to say something to the user.

Comment: the custom data validation formula `=AND(LEN(A1)=9,NOT(ISNUMBER(--LEFT(A1,1))),NOT(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,2,1))),ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1,7)))` works for me, and as @BruceWayne stated you can customize the error message.  any vba would just be reinventing what is inherent in excel..

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has stated, use data validation.

Here is a macro, however.

Change `[A1]` to the cell you want to monitor.

Put this in the worksheet object of the sheet with the cell you want to monitor.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, [A1]) Is Nothing Then
    If Not [A1] Like "[A-z][A-z]#######" Then
        [A1].Select
        MsgBox ("Invalid value in A1!")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Edit: Just because, here is a solution for multiple cells.

This will also display one messagebox that lists the incorrect cells.

It will also color the cells red if they are incorrect.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MonRange As Range
'What range do we want to monitor?
Set MonRange = [A1:A10]
'---------------------------------
If Not Intersect(Target, MonRange) Is Nothing Then
    Dim c As Range, Inc As String
    Inc = "Incorrect Cells: " & Chr(13) & "-----------------" & Chr(13)
    For Each c In Intersect(Target, MonRange)
        If Not c Like "[A-z][A-z]#######" Then
            Inc = Inc & c.Address(False,False) & ","
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 180, 180)
        Else
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next c
    If Len(Inc) <> 36 Then MsgBox (Left(Inc,Len(Inc)-1))
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the `[A1]` in your IF statement to `Target`.  Then the OP can change the test range to a larger number of cells.

Comment: It wouldn't work like that - you have to make sure target is only a single cell in that case. You would have to change more than the `[A1]` is what i'm saying, in case someone pastes in a range. That's fine too, but not what OP asked for. You could modify it to use `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` and this would still monitor single cell changes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you could make sure it is one cell, then check if it intersects a larger range. You are probably correct in that the OP only wants one cell.  I was just making a note if a larger range of checked cells is desired.

Comment: For larger ranges, you could change `[A1]` to `[A1:A10]` and use, `For Each c in Intersect(Target,[A1:A10]) If Not c Like "[A-z][A-z]#######" Then ...`